# how can I loop over a multiple file upload then add to my json array?

Tags: php

I would like to loop through multiple file uploads and the add them to my json

This is what I currently have for one upload:

```
$file_prefix = md5_file($tmp_file);
$file_name = $file_prefix . "_" . rand(1000, 99999) . "_{$session_check_data['id']}".".jpg";
$target_file = $vehicle_image_folder . "/".$file_name;

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tmp_file);


$image = new \Gumlet\ImageResize($tmp_file);

 if($width > 1200) {
        $image->resizeToWidth(1200);
 }

$image->save($target_file, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);

if ($this->request->get('upload_thumb')) {
    $thumbnail_file = $vehicle_image_folder . "/thumb_".$file_name;
    $this->app['monolog']->info("thumbs required");
    $image = new \Gumlet\ImageResize($target_file);
    $image->resizeToWidth(400);
    $image->save($thumbnail_file, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
}
```

Here is what I attempted to do:

```
$files = array();
$l = 3;
foreach ($tmp_file as $k => $l) {
    $file_prefix = md5_file($k);
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
            $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}
$counter = 1;


foreach ($files as $file) {
    $count = $counter++;

    $file_name = $file_prefix . "_" . rand(1000, 99999) . "_{$session_check_data['id']}".".jpg";
    $target_file = $vehicle_image_folder . "/".$file_name;
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file);

    $image = new \Gumlet\ImageResize($file);

    if ($width > 1200) {
        $image->resizeToWidth(1200);
    }

    $image->save($target_file, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);

    if ($this->request->get('upload_thumb')) {
        $thumbnail_file = $vehicle_image_folder . "/thumb_" . $file_name;
        $this->app['monolog']->info("thumbs required");
        $image = new \Gumlet\ImageResize($target_file);
        $image->resizeToWidth(400);
        $image->save($thumbnail_file, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
    }
}
```

then I would like to return the 3 images in my JSON in the loc, maybe loc1, loc2, loc3?:

```
return $this->app->json(['success' => 1, 'info' => 'uploaded', 'loc' => $file_name]);
```

I would like to be able to show the 3 images that have been uploaded

Comment: What are the variables `$count` and `$counter` for? You assign and increment them, but never use them.

Comment: `$files` is a 2-dimensional array, so `$file` is an array. What do you expect `getimagesize($file)` to do with that?

Comment: Why don't you use `$file_prefix` in the first `foreach` loop? When you use it in the second loop, it's the MD5 of the last file from the first loop.